# How can I dynamically add or remove required fields in Yup?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, react-hook-form, yup

I want the field "taxOffice" to be required or not based on the value received in the "membershipType" field. How can I achieve this using Yup?

"When I use the when() function, I encounter the following error: 'Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: branch is not a function.' I haven't been able to find a solution for this.

Yup version: 1.3.2"

```js
const NewUserSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    company: Yup.object().shape({
      membershipType: Yup.string().required(),
      taxOffice: Yup.string().when('membershipType', {
        is: (val) => val === "GOVERNMENT_INSTITUTION",
        then: Yup.string().required(),
        otherwise: Yup.string(),
      }),
  }),
})
```